# AMPscript Best Practices

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Listening to a webinar from Eliot Harper on Adv. AMPscript (and it's great!), and he mentions - among other things - that the use of **AttributeValue** is a best practice.

Overall, though, is there a full collection of best practices anywhere? I haven't been able to find a comprehensive best practice document for ampscript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information I find, I will write out the best practices i find. Any edits and suggestions are more than welcome to the addition:

- Use **AttributeValue** to pull in field values for more stable builds
- Use **RedirectTo** on any link including ampscript to ensure proper tracking
- Use **MicroSiteURL** or **CloudPagesURL** when linking to SFMC landing pages, as this generates an encrypted query string (added security) + you can get parameters passed using e.g. AMPscript
- Use **LookupRows** combined with **RowCount** and **Field**, instead of doing a direct Lookup for a field value, to ensure you are getting a value and can handle when you do not retrieve a result